# Mounting hdds in Solaris

Tags: solaris, zfs

I'm new to Solaris and trying to set up zfs pool but when I try this command: `zpool create mirror tank c3t2d0 c3t3d0`, I get this error: `cannot open c3t2d0 no such device in /dev/dsk`.

After checking `/dev/dsk`, i saw that every possible name is listed  but not the devices that are listed when I use the command format.

Answer (score 2):

You can list available disks with the `format` command.

```
[root@isis /]$ format
Searching for disks...done

AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
0. c1t0d0 <SEAGATE-ST3146855FC-0003 cyl 65533 alt 2 hd 4 sec 1093>
   /pci@9,600000/pci@1/SUNW,qlc@4/fp@0,0/ssd@w2200001d3866102c,0
1. c1t1d0 <SEAGATE-ST3146855FC-0003-136.73GB>
   /pci@9,600000/pci@1/SUNW,qlc@4/fp@0,0/ssd@w2200001d38660d6e,0
.....
15. c2t11d0 <SEAGATE-ST3146855FC-0003-136.73GB>
      /pci@8,600000/SUNW,qlc@2/fp@0,0/ssd@w2100001d3863b8b9,0
Specify disk (enter its number): ^D
```

Comment: I think he already knows this... "but not the devices that are listed when I use the command format."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've got the pool name and vdev mixed up slightly. It should be:

```
zpool create poolname mirror cXtYdZ ...
```

The pool name comes first. `mirror` is part of the vdev so is listed immediately before the disk list.

Try it this way around, but output from `format </dev/null` would be useful too.